# <IfModule> filename vs. module id

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

The [Apache documentation on IfModule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/core.html#ifmodule) states

> The module name argument is the file name of the module, at the time it was compiled. For example, `mod_rewrite.c`.  ...

However, Apache 2.2 seems to accept the module id too. So, these both work:

```
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
```

and

```
<IfModule filter_module>
```

Is that true for all Apache versions? Should the first version be prefered or does the second yield any benefits?

<sub>I'm asking because [HTML5 boilerplate uses the module id](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/commit/473af90bdbc4728b8082565636228474a10ce4a3) instead of the filename</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache 2.2 introduced the use of the module identifier as an option.  See the [documentation for 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#ifmodule).

Comment: Oh, how could I miss that...

Comment: @ShaneMadden: that link actually states it got introduced with 2.1 and later. But perhaps it changed since you wrote this answer.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Although 2.2 would be the first stable/production-ready version. The odd-numbered minor version numbers signify development-only versions.

Comment: @MrWhite thanks, never knew. I know this scheme from others but I wasn't aware Apache was using it.